# Python write into a file

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python and I have problem with some exercise. I got file with 1000 numbers(the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HRUX0w4lDZc9gVBrSUro5XzBjNBqnS7S) and I have to write even numbers into file. The problem is that all of these numbers have to be on new lines. Here's my code, please help:

```
with open("dane.txt", 'r') as liczby:
a=[]
for i in liczby:
    i=int(i.strip())
    if (int(i%2 == 0)):
        a.append(i)
        b=[a]
        print(str(a))

with open("parzyste.txt", 'w') as p:
    p.write(str(i)+"\n")
```

Comment: You need to write them one by one, not as a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it.

```
with open("dane.txt", 'r') as liczby:
    with open("parzyste.txt", 'w') as p:
        for i in liczby:
            i=int(i.strip())
            if (int(i%2 == 0)):
                print(str(i))
                p.write(str(i)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `writelines` to write all values at once on separate lines.

```py
output = []
with open("dane.txt", 'r') as liczby:
    for i in liczby:
        i = int(i.strip())
        if int(i%2 == 0):
            output.append(str(i) + "\n")

with open("parzyste.txt", 'w') as p:
    p.writelines(output)
```